# Recojer el valor en excepcion en numericUpDown

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excepciones

Tengo varios controles del tipo numericUpDown, el caso es que cada uno de ellos tiene un valor minimo y otro valor maximo por defecto.
El usuario tiene una botonera donde pulsa un boton con un numero del 1 al 9 y un boton especial para borrar el ultimo digito.
Al hacer click en un boton que no sea el de borrar, el valor del numerico se incrementa y es lo que puede desencadenar la excepcion, lo mismo que si al borrar nos quedamos con un valor por debajo del minimo
Lo que necesito es que cuando el usuario ponga un valor superior al maximo, capturar la excepcion y poner el valor maximo por defecto de ese control, y lo mismo para el valor minimo.

Estoy intentando hacerlo usando tanto OverflowException ( por la que no entra)
como Exception, por la que obviamente entra pero donde no veo en ningun lugar (salvo el mensaje) el valor que tiene el numericUpDown cuando ha saltado la excepcion.

Todos los botones implementan el codigo que pondre a continuacion y ultimoNumerico es el ultimo numerico sobre el que se tenia el foco para que sea ese el que se modifica.
(Boton que termina en B es el que borra el ultimo digito)

Basicamente lo que necesito es saber que Excepcion hay que buscar para recojer dicho valor.

```
     private void clickBoton(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        string aux = ((Button)o).Name.Substring(3, 1);
        string tag = (((Button)o).Tag == null) ? "" : ((Button)o).Tag.ToString();
        try
        {
            if (aux == "B")
            {
                string auxB = decimal.ToInt32(ultimoNumerico.Value).ToString();
                if (aux.Length > 1)
                {
                    auxB = auxB.Substring(0, auxB.Length - 1);
                    ultimoNumerico.Value = int.Parse(auxB);
                }
                else
                {
                     ultimoNumerico.Value = ultimoNumerico.Minimum;
                }                    
            }
            else
            {
                Int32 auxNum = decimal.ToInt32(ultimoNumerico.Value) * 10 + int.Parse(aux);
                ultimoNumerico.Value = auxNum;
            }
        }
        catch (OverflowException ox)
        {
            object ob = ox.Data;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ultimoNumerico.Value > ultimoNumerico.Maximum)
            {
                ultimoNumerico.Value = ultimoNumerico.Maximum;
            }
            else
            {
                ultimoNumerico.Value = ultimoNumerico.Minimum;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la excepción que recibes, incluyendo la pila de llamadas?

Comment: Me entra por ArgumentOutOfRangeException pero actualdata viene a null. Por otro lado he conseguido llegar a la operativa que queria usando el boton que ha pulsado, pero si que me gustaria resolver esta duda para aprender. gracias.

Comment: por ejemplo el mensaje es: "Value of '34' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'".  en _innerexception viene a null. No se si algun otro valor puede ayudar a saber que excepcion permite capturar el valor de ese control en el momento de saltar la excepcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta concreta a tu duda es que **no es posible recoger el valor de la excepción que lanza el control `NumericUpDown`**, a menos que estés dispuesto a hacer un parse del mensaje en sí, lo que no parece una buena idea.

La razón resulta obvia cuando examinamos el código fuente para la propiedad `Value` del control `NumericUpDown` ([código fuente](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/NumericUpDown.cs,05e91d1da762a5c3)):

```
public Decimal Value {
    get {
        if (UserEdit) {
            ValidateEditText();
        }
        return currentValue;
    }

    set {
        if (value != currentValue) {

            if (!initializing && ((value < minimum) || (value > maximum))) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value", SR.GetString(SR.InvalidBoundArgument, "Value", value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), "'Minimum'", "'Maximum'"));
            }
            else {
                currentValue = value;                       

                OnValueChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                currentValueChanged = true;    
                UpdateEditText();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En particular, nota cómo el control crea la excepción `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` usando el constructor con 2 parámetros solamente (`string paramName, string message`). Es debido a esto que la propiedad `ActualValue` queda a `null`.

Lo ideal hubiera sido que el control cree y lanze la excepción de esta manera, usando el constructor con 3 parámetros (`string paramName, object actualValue, string message`):

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
    "Value",
    value, // esto es lo que hace falta
    SR.GetString(SR.InvalidBoundArgument, "Value", value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), "'Minimum'", "'Maximum'"));
```

Si hubiera sido de esta forma, entonces la propiedad `ActualValue` contendría el valor deseado al atrapar la excepción. Pero ya que no tenemos control sobre el código del control `NumericUpDown`, no tienes otra que de usar una lógica que no dependa de esta excepción.

Comment: muchas gracias, ojala para futuras versiones tengan esto en cuenta

Comment: Sería bueno. Pero a menos que alguien lo pida, no creo que cambie. Siempre tienes la opción de reportar el "defecto" si te interesa: http://connect.microsoft.com/.

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso prueba a guardar en una variable que tengas alcance desde el catch el valor que quieres escribir:

```
private void clickBoton(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        string aux = ((Button)o).Name.Substring(3, 1);
        string tag = (((Button)o).Tag == null) ? "" : ((Button)o).Tag.ToString();
        var valor = ultimoNumerico.Minimum;

        if (aux == "B")
        {
            string auxB = decimal.ToInt32(ultimoNumerico.Value).ToString();
            if (aux.Length > 1)
            {
                auxB = auxB.Substring(0, auxB.Length - 1);
                valor = int.Parse(auxB);
            }
            else
            {
                valor = ultimoNumerico.Minimum;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Int32 auxNum = decimal.ToInt32(ultimoNumerico.Value) * 10 + int.Parse(aux);
            valor = auxNum;
        }
        try
        {
            ultimoNumerico.Value = valor;
        }

        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            if (valor > ultimoNumerico.Maximum)
            {
                ultimoNumerico.Value = ultimoNumerico.Maximum;
            }
            else
            {
                ultimoNumerico.Value = ultimoNumerico.Minimum;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: en ActualData me viene el valor null, asi que no me sirve, si entra por alli pero no encuentro la manera de recuperar el valor que desencadenado la excepcion